# Plotting Multiple Data Frames on one axis

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am relatively new to Python and am currently trying to plot multiple data frames on one axis.

At the moment I have a function that outputs a data frame highlighting cumulative percentage. I want to use this function for 5 different files and then plot the outputs on a single axis for comparison. I can output 5 graphs but am currently struggling to combine them into one.

I have been using the `dataframe.plot()` function, but as of yet cannot find a solution. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

do:

```
ax = dataframe.plot(...)
dataframe2.plot(..., ax=ax)
dataframe3.plot(..., ax=ax)
...
```

So all plots are on the same matplotlib Axes object.